# how to get summary table with by () into a table or data.frame

Tags: r

I tried to get a summary stat of a variable `Change_1`.
I can get what I want by using codes `by( df3.1_P2.1$Change_1, df3.1_P2.1$AGEGROUP_CLA, summary )`.

The output is looks like following:

[image]

I would like to somehow to get those info into a table which I can export to an excel file. what should I do? Maybe `by()` is not the best way to do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `aggregate`. For example, try this `aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, summary)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `rbind` the output from `by` to get a dataframe which can be exported to excel.

```
res <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, by(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, summary)))
res

#  Min. X1st.Qu. Median     Mean X3rd.Qu. Max.
#4 21.4    22.80   26.0 26.66364    30.40 33.9
#6 17.8    18.65   19.7 19.74286    21.00 21.4
#8 10.4    14.40   15.2 15.10000    16.25 19.2

writexl::write_xlsx(res, 'data.xlsx')
```

Comment: Is it a way to add number of observation into `res` (add col `n` )? If so, how? j